# Firebase error with Google Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-signin

[image]

I am trying out google firebase authentication for my college project. I have implemented the login and signup with email functionality using firebase and it works fine. But, when i implemented the sign up with google functionality, its show this. When i click on advanced then it works and i can login.

I have to remove this warning. As this is just simple college project, i dont want to verify. Give me a solution and if its not possible without verification, then tell me how can i verify this website.I dont even have a domain name for this project.

Comment: Is the project hosted? or are you running it from the localhost? or have you hosted it on your system and port forwarded to the internet?

Comment: I am running it from a local host. It's still in developing phase

Answer (score 0):

have you hosted your app may be on netlify or vercel?
In that case, you have to add a custom domain i.e. your hosted web address in the **firebase console > authentication settings > authorized domain**.